# Script to run a program on all files in a folder

Tags: file, batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to write a script that runs a program on all files in a directory of a certain file type, in windows. This is the code I have:

```
cd files

for /f %%f in (*.raw)
do
        %path2% --32 -z --filter "peakPicking true" %f%
done
```

but it doesn't seem to work. I get an error "the syntax of the command is incorrect" I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Type `for /?` in command prompt and read the help text carefully!

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing all of your script the syntax should look like this.

```
 for %%f in (*.raw) do %path2% --32 -z --filter "peakPicking true" %%f
```